# forEach processes array of DOM elements through an one

Tags: javascript, foreach

I encountered a strange behavior of simple JS code. Elements processed through an one.

```
var a = document.getElementsByClassName('nahren');
Array.prototype.forEach.call(a, function(e) {
    e.classList.remove('nahren')
})
```

[Example on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tr2kdj0L/)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Collections returned by `getElementsByClassName` are "live": if you change them to disqualify them from the selector, they disappear from the collection. This makes iterating over them wonky. Use `querySelectorAll('.nahren')`, which returns a "dead" collection, or pin the "live" collection by cloning it:

```
var deadArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(liveCollection);
deadArray.forEach(...)
```

Answer (score 3):

Amadan, has already answered correctly,  but here is another implementation in which you can clone them using ES6.

```js
var a = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('nahren')); //clone array
Array.prototype.forEach.call(a, function(e,i) {
  e.classList.remove('nahren');
})
```

```css
div#container div {
  height: 30px;
  width: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.hren {
  outline: 1px red solid;
}

.hren.nahren {
  outline: 1px blue solid;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
<div class="hren nahren"></div>
<div class="hren nahren"></div>
<div class="hren nahren"></div>
<div class="hren nahren"></div>
<div class="hren nahren"></div>
<div class="hren nahren"></div>
<div class="hren nahren"></div>
<div class="hren nahren"></div>
<div class="hren nahren"></div>
<div class="hren nahren"></div>
  <div>
```

Comment: Yeah, nice. I still haven't switched over to answering with ES6 by default :P +1 for you

Comment: It's awesome (comparatively speaking). It's just that I think a lot of the people are still stuck developing for IE6. >.<

Comment: You can just use `a.forEach()`.  After using `Array.from()`, you have a real array so you can use `a.forEach()`.

Answer (score 1):

I have attached the code snippet for your requirement. In your case you cannot use class name `'nahren'` as the selector. Because on removing the class `'nahren'` once from your DOM element, your object is not the same any more. You could use the `'hren'` class for selecting the DOM object, since you are removing the `'nahren'` class only your DOM selector will not change.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      div {
        height: 30px;
        width: 100px;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
      }
      
      .hren {
        outline: 1px red solid
      }
      
      .hren.nahren {
        outline: 1px blue solid
      }
    </style>
    <script>
 function RemoveClass(){
  var a = document.getElementsByClassName('hren');
     Array.prototype.forEach.call(a, function(e,i) {
        e.classList.remove('nahren');
     })
 }
          
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="hren nahren"></div>
    <div class="hren nahren"></div>
    <div class="hren nahren"></div>
    <div class="hren nahren"></div>
    <div class="hren nahren"></div>
    <div class="hren nahren"></div>
    <div class="hren nahren"></div>
    <div class="hren nahren"></div>
    <div class="hren nahren"></div>
    <div class="hren nahren"></div>
 <button onclick="RemoveClass()">Remove</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: umm, what is the purpose of this snippet ??